# Remove public from url lumen

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, lumen

I'm working on an microservice based arhitecture with Lumen.
The local environement is working fine, but the production server needs  adjustments, because it can't have the same link structure, and I want the code to be the same in every env.

In the local env I created virtual hosts for every microservice, like for e.g. books.xyz, and authors.xyz
that point to the /public folder, so link structure **DOESN'T** contain public.
On live, it is hosted like server .servername.com/books and beta.servername.com/authors.
I have started developing an admin panel with lumen ( /admin ) but the problem is that the link structure is too different, and doesn't work on production. ( css/js assets get 404'd  etc.)

How can I remove the /public in the production URL?

**I don't want to move everything from public folder into root, because of security reasons!**

I have tried creating a .htaccess file on the root, and the following, but none of them worked :

```
# <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# RewriteEngine On
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/books/public/
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]
# RewriteRule ^game/(.*)$ /books/public/$1 [L,QSA]
# </IfModule>
```

or

```
# <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#   RewriteEngine On
#   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ books/public/$1 [L]
# </IfModule>
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ books/public/$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
```